# Is there a query language to filter array?

Tags: php, sql

I was wondering if there is a library that implements a SQL-like interface to access data in array, e.g.

Input:

```
[
    ['name' => 'Tom', 'age' => 27, 'location' => ['country' => 'GB']],
    ['name' => 'Jerry', 'age' => 16, 'location' => ['country' => 'LT']],
    ['name' => 'Stuart', 'age' => 26, 'location' => ['country' => 'GB']]
]
```

Fictional query:

```
SELECT name, location.country FROM {input} WHERE age > 18 ORDER BY age DESC
```

Which would produce a variation of:

```
[
    ['name' => 'Tom', 'location.country' => 'GB'],
    ['name' => 'Tom', 'location.country' => 'GB']
]
```

Note, I am perfectly aware of `array_filter` and alike implementations that I could put together on the spot. I am looking for query like interface to access data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ, with PHP implementations such as [phpLinq](https://phplinq.codeplex.com/) or [LINQ for PHP](https://linqforphp.codeplex.com/) or [plinq](https://plinq.codeplex.com/)

Comment: It seems that every single linq library has been discontinued. I wonder whether it is because it proved not useful of for other reasons. The most up to date implementation that I have found under "linq" name is https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo. The other, is ArrayQuery mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to be the closest of all available alternatives:

https://github.com/braincrafted/arrayquery

`ArrayQuery` does not provide query language, though it does provide query API, e.g.

```
$thorinsCompany = [
    [ 'name' => 'Bilbo Baggins', 'race' => 'Hobbit' ],
    [ 'name' => 'Gandalf', 'race' => 'Wizard' ],
    [ 'name' => 'Thorin Oakenshild', 'race' => 'Dwarf' ],
    [ 'name' => 'Balin', 'race' => 'Dwarf'],
    [ 'name' => 'Bifur', 'race' => 'Dwarf'],
    // ...
];

$query->from($thorinsCompany);
$query->where('race', 'Dwarf')
$query->where('age', 50, '>');
$results = $query->findAll();
```

On a related note, Mongo PHP extension provides SQL to Mongo API translation, http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php. The basic logic could be used as a guiding example for someone who set their foot on developing SQL interface to PHP arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the reason why there aren't any actively used SQL-like query languages for arrays in PHP is performance. Using something like ArrayQuery (which I am the author of) already results in a performance penalty. A query language would result in further decreased performance which makes most of the time no sense.

ArrayQuery was also inspired by [Doctrines QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html), which is, a way to transform SQL into system based on objects that is more natural in a OOP language like PHP.